# Adding a UISearchBar on a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an *UITableView* and I did put an *UISearchbar* on it. What I want to achieve is that if a user is going to scroll i want the *UISearchbar* element to be fixed on the top, plus I want the first row of the *UITableView* fixed as well. Is there any sample code for this ?

So far every sample I found the *UISearchbar* wasn't fixed at the top, if you scroll it disappears.  One way to get the *UISearchbar* element fixed could be, if I put an *UIView* under both elements (*UITableView* and *UISearchbar*) and put those two consecutively among themselves (just a thought of me don't know if this actually is working). However i'm not sure if this is the appropriate way to go and it also wouldn't fix that I want the first row fixed as well.

I'm kinda new to this stuff would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the fixed search bar: just make it a sibling of the tableView.

For the fixed first row: maybe make it the section header and have only 1 section, or make it a sibling view.

Comment: how can i make the search bar as sibling ?

Comment: you'll want your view controller to subclass UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, then you'll have a UIView as your view instead of a UITableView. In that UIView you'll want to add the SearchDisplayController and a UITableView. You'll then need to implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols.

Comment: I had it that way, but I had to make it a UITableViewController so that I could use the pull to refresh.  So how can I fix the search bar?

Comment: You don't need to use a UITableViewController to use pullToRefresh -- take a look at `enablePullToRefreshForTableView:` in https://github.com/jessecurry/keylime/blob/master/src/KLViewController.m for an example.